# How to extract countries from a text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, geography

I use Python 3 (I also have Python 2 installed) and I want to extract countries or cities from a short text.
For example, `text = "I live in Spain"` or `text = "United States (New York), United Kingdom (London)"`.

The answer for countries:

1. Spain
2. [United States, United Kingdom]

I tried to install `geography` but I am unable to run `pip install geography`. I get this error:

> Collecting geography   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>   requirement geography (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>   for geography

It looks like `geography` only works with Python 2.

I also have `geopandas`, but I don't know how to extract the required info from text using geopandas.

Comment: @smci The package is called `geograpy`, not `geography`.

Comment: @MaxiMouse: ok, then should this be closed as typo? Also, you could add that as answer.

Comment: @smci Yes, it should probably be closed as a typo. I don't think this could be an answer.

Comment: @MaxiMouse: on reflection, the question asks the broader *"How to extract countries from a text?"*, isn't strictly tied to any package, and has good answers, so we should let it stand.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you could use pycountry for your task (it also works with python 3):

**pip install pycountry**

```
import pycountry
text = "United States (New York), United Kingdom (London)"
for country in pycountry.countries:
    if country.name in text:
        print(country.name)
```

Comment: Cool. But it will not work with abbreviations, right? Do you know something additional for recognizing abbreviations and passing them to country names?

Comment: For example, `BVI` -> `British Virgin Islands`

Comment: every country object has the attributes alpha_2 and alpha_3 which are abbreviations of the country. (E.g: Germany.alpha_2 = DE, Germany.alpha_3 = DEU)

Comment: I hope that that can cover your use case see also: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry

Comment: British Virgin Islands is in pycountry, but it's code is as `alpha_3='VGB', alpha_2='VG'` @Markus

Comment: 'Korea' is also not recognized.

Answer (score 3):

There is a newer version for this library that supports python3 named **geograpy3**

```
pip install geograpy3
```

It allows you to extract place names from a URL or text, and add context to those names -- for example distinguishing between a country, region or city.

Example:

```
import geograpy
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('maxent_ne_chunker')
nltk.download('words')
url = 'http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-26919928'
places = geograpy.get_place_context(url=url)
```

You can find more details under [this link:](https://pypi.org/project/geograpy3/)

Comment: I've seen this exact text many times "Geograpy allows you to extract place names from a URL or text", but all websites / forums / github project examples show only how to use Geograpy with url and I haven't come across an example with a regular string (neither does it work if we just replace the url in the example code with a regular text)

Comment: @MihaelaGrigore `places = geograpy.get_place_context(text="my text from Germany")`